# Spectral Projection and GNS in Commutative Case

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

For $N>4$, let $A=C([0,N])$ and $1_A=\mathbf{1}_{[0,N]}$ (**the identity on $A$**). Consider $\operatorname{id}:=\operatorname{id}_{[0,N]}=(t\mapsto t)$ (**not the identity on $A$ but $f(t)=t$**) and the functional $\varphi:=\operatorname{ev}_{N-2}$, $f\mapsto f(N-2)$. I am interested in the spectral projection $\mathbf{1}_{\{N-2\}}(\operatorname{id})$ and the GNS representation $(\mathsf{H}_\varphi,\pi_\varphi,\xi_\varphi)$. I guess I'll start with the GNS representation as that seems more straightforward.

The nullspace of $\varphi$, $N_\varphi$ consists of those functions that vanish at $N-2$. We quotient to get the (one-dimensional?) space of functions $A/N_\varphi$ which agree at $N-2$. We have an inner product:
$$\langle f+N_\varphi,g+N_\varphi\rangle=\overline{f(N-2)}g(N-2).$$
We take the (trivial?) Hilbert space completion $\overline{A/N_\varphi}=\mathsf{H}_\varphi$. The representation $\pi_\varphi:A\rightarrow B(\mathsf{H}_\varphi)$ is:
$$\pi_\varphi(f)(g+N_\varphi)=fg+N_\varphi.$$
The cyclic vector is $\xi_\varphi=1_A+N_\varphi$. The importance of this vector is that it is an eigenvector of eigenvalue $N-2$ for $\pi_\varphi(\operatorname{id})$ as:
$$\pi_\varphi(\operatorname{id})(1_A+N_\varphi)=\operatorname{id}+N_\varphi=(N-2)(1_A+N_\varphi),$$
as $\operatorname{id}(N-2)=N-2=(N-2)\varphi(1_A)=\varphi((N-2)1_A)$. So in this representation $N-2$ is an eigenvalue.

Now onto $\mathbf{1}_{N-2}(\operatorname{id})$. I am wondering is it possible to describe this concretely. When I try and play around with $L^\infty([0,N])$ and $L^2([0,N])$ and multipliers and such I cannot get it to work, and the best I think I can do is something like:
$$\mathbf{1}_{(N-2-\varepsilon,N-2+\varepsilon)}(\operatorname{id})(f)(t)=\begin{cases}f(t)& \text{ if }|t-(N-2)|<\varepsilon \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
I don't think it should be zero though in the generality I am interested in. I think I should be looking at the enveloping von Neumann algebra $\pi_U(A)''$, and then my understanding is that $\mathbf{1}_{\{N-2\}}(\operatorname{id})$ is the projection onto the kernel of $\operatorname{id}-(N-2)1_A$, and if I have the big $\mathsf{H}_U$ then I at least have $\xi_\varphi\in\mathsf{H}_U$ and so we should have something like:
$$\mathbf{1}_{\{N-2\}}(\pi_U(\operatorname{id}))\xi_{\varphi}=\xi_\varphi,\qquad (*),$$
which might be written as $\mathbf{1}_{\{N-2\}}(\operatorname{id})\xi_{\varphi}=\xi_\varphi$, and so  $\mathbf{1}_{\{N-2\}}(\operatorname{id})\neq 0$.

My questions I guess are:

> 1. Does this all check out? In particular do I have to be more careful with the quotient map in (*)
> 2. If $\mathbf{1}_{\{N-2\}}(\operatorname{id})$ is indeed non-zero in $\pi_U(A)''\subset B(\mathsf{H}_U)$, is there any hope of describing it concretely?

What I am hoping to do eventually is condition states $\omega$ (on what algebra now I am not sure, $A$ or normal extensions to $\pi_U(A)''$) by $p_{N-2}:=\mathbf{1}_{\{N-2\}}(\operatorname{id})$:
$$\omega\mapsto \frac{\omega(p_{N-2}\cdot p_{N-2})}{\omega(p_{N-2})},$$

so that, for example, we could condition $(\operatorname{ev}_{N-3}+\operatorname{ev}_{N-2})/2$ to $\varphi=\operatorname{ev}_{N-2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=C_0(X)$ where $X$ is a Hausdorff space. Then the pure states are the evaluation maps, which are also the characters. As such $A/N_\varphi$ is one-dimensional for every pure state $\varphi$.

So while your GNS construction works it is pretty much overkill, in particular every non-zero element of $A/N_\varphi$ is a cyclic vector and $\pi(f)$ is always proportional to the identity (ie has an eigenvalue). The spectral projection of the point $\{N-2\}$ on the representation $A/N_{ev_{N-2}}$ is given by $\Bbb1$, the identity operator.

If you want to find the spectral projection in the enveloping von Neumann algebra it goes like this:

One construction of $A''$ is as the bi-commutant of the image of $A$ in the representation

$$\bigoplus_{\varphi} A/N_{\varphi}$$
where $\varphi$ sums over all pure states / irreducible representations. In this case these are the characters so you are summing over
$$\bigoplus_{x\in X} \Bbb C = \ell^2(X)$$
where the action of $f\in C_0(X)$ one the summand corresponding to $x\in X$ is given by multiplication with $f(x)$. The bi-commutant of this image is $\ell^\infty(X)$.

The spectral projection of a set $S\subseteq X$ in $A''$ is then given by pointwise multiplication with the characterstic function $\chi_S$ of $S$ on $\ell^2(X)$.

Comment: Firstly, thank you. Secondly, what is the issue with the complex conjugation? Is $\ell^{\infty}([0,N])$ the big beast that I think it is? ALL bounded functions $[0,N]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$? Including delta functions? Cool. I can see that $C([0,N])$ embeds in that. $\ell^2([0,N])$ is so small in comparison, but great as can talk of delta functions. So if I have $f\in \ell^{\infty}([0,N])$ and $g\in \ell^2([0,N])$, $f:g\mapsto fg\in \ell^2([0,N])$. Cool. The spectral measure of $\operatorname{id}$ is $S\mapsto M_{\mathbf{1}_S}$,

Comment: so $\mathbf{1}_{\{N-2\}}(\operatorname{id})(f)=f(N-2)\delta_{N-2}$. Now for conditioning, the evaluation functional extends to $\ell^{\infty}([0,N])$... ah this is really cool thank you.

Comment: The missed complex conjugation is in the scalar product:
$$\langle f + N_\varphi, g+ N_\varphi\rangle = \overline{f(N-2)}g(N-2)$$
$\ell^\infty([0,N])$ does refer to the algebra of all bounded functions (looks like I forgot to mention this) in particular it doesn't see the topology of $X$ at all (provided $X$ is Hausdorff)  --- Edit: After noticing that the \overline isn't displayed in my comment I checked the unrendered version of your question and noticed that you had included the \overline in the question, my browser just isn't rendering it correctly. So there was no error

Comment: thank you, yes I was wondering about that overline. I am seeing some odd rendering on mobile lately.

Comment: FYI: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4213274/19352

Comment: Thanks, it seems I was too confident regarding mis-remembered information. The enveloping von Neumann algebra lives not on the sum of the pure states, but on the sum of all states. That makes it much bigger thing, what I gave you is probably a sub-algebra.